# where to find config.vm.boot_timeout?

Tags: vagrant, homestead

Hi I want to edit the config.vm.boot_timeout in vagrant because I am having problem in booting up the vagrant. where i can find the config.vm.boot_timeout ?and what value should i put ? I am in windows8.1 x86

[image]
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to run vagrant command to get the location of the vagrant file. And then make changes to the variable **config.vm.boot_timeout** ([Reference](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/))

1. The default value of the variable is 300. You can try changing the default values.
2. Check if you have the latest version and it is compatible with your OS.

Follow the steps given [here](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/wiki/%60vagrant-up%60-hangs-at-%22Waiting-for-VM-to-boot.-This-can-take-a-few-minutes%22)

Also, a whole bunch of solution's are provided [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/586059/vagrant-error-connection-timeout-retrying)

Answer (score 3):

If it's windows 10 OS, then by default virtualization is disabled in BIOS level. If we make the value as enabled and restart the system and run vagrant up. Then it will works fine.

Steps to Do:

1. Restart the system and press <kbd>F1</kbd>.
2. Goto BIOS settings and enable Virtualization.
3. Press <kbd>F10</kbd> (Save and exit)
4. Run `vagrant up`.

Comment: In my case, Virtualization was enabled, but I had to disable Hyper-V since I was trying to use VirtualBox

Answer (score 2):

I could not find `config.vm.boot_timeout` in config files. That left me with the question on where to add this setting. This looks to be working for me:

In the root directory of your Vagrant install, there's the `Vagrantfile` file. There, I added `config.vm.boot_timeout = 600` just after `Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|`.

I'm using Vagrant 2.2.19.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

1. login with :gui by login/pass: vagrant/vagrant
2. modify the `/etc/rc.local` file 
   to include the line `sh /etc/init.d/networking restart` just before `exit 0`
3. disable :gui
4. vagrant up or vagrant reload

https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/391#issuecomment-2078383