# Vagrant Issue: Which Vagrant file is the correct one to edit?

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead, vagrantfile

Recently I bought a course on sitepoint.com for learning the Laravel Homestead framework.

I've been running into so many issues with simply just setting it up on VirtualBox. Mainly the issue is Vagrant timing out when trying to connect to the homestead7 box. Going through what it says when it times out, there are no errors with it booting, the connection just times out. So the solution is to configure the config.vm.boot_timeout variable to a larger number.

However, in which Vagrant file is that in? There's 4: One in the Homestead directory itself, one on my User directory in .vargrant.d/boxes/"Name of the box"/1.1.0/virtualbox, and a few others scattered around. None of which contain a variable called "config.vm.boot_timeout".

Should I just do a fresh install of Vagrant and VirtualBox?

[Here's](https://gist.github.com/BigDaddyDeadpoo1/44e5f3ca772b4c984fd62cd4660b64eb) where the connect times out on `vagrant up` or `vagrant reload --provision`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32731629/where-to-find-config-vm-boot-timeout

Comment: Possible duplicate of [where to find config.vm.boot\_timeout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32731629/where-to-find-config-vm-boot-timeout)

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Based on comments it appears in this case the problem was due to the `vagrant init <boxname>` step not happening yet, so the local Vagrantfile was not created.

The Vagrantfile which is used will depend on where you ran the `vagrant up` command. In your case it should be under `C:\Homestead\Homestead`.

You can see a bit more detail on the search order for Vagrantfile in the [Vagrantfile docs](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/).

There might not be a default `config.vm.boot_timeout` value, but you can always add it. (By default I think most Vagrantfile leave it out.)

To troubleshoot the problem you might also turn on the GUI mode. See my answer here for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23742373/9965

Comment: I actually figured out my issue. I needed to initiate a Vagrantfile for my Homestead box with the same name of the box I created. So I did it like this `vagrant init laravel/homestead`. It makes no real sense that was the way to fix it, but it did, so I'm not complaining.

Comment: @BigDaddyDeadpoo1 I'm glad you were able to get it working. Vagrant projects typically start either with the `vagrant init boxname` step or copying an existing Vagrantfile. You can see the [getting started docs](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/getting-started/) for an example.